# How to use SBT with external ivy configuration

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

We would like to use home made Ivy resolvers and ivy file in a Play project. I have followed the documentation on external ivysettings and ivy.xml.

The resolving of our own artefacts goes ok, but when compiling the project, the Scala library/compiler is missing from classpath. The error from sbt: http://pastebin.com/6JHK0LQh

I don't know why the compiler is suddenly missing. Will SBT stop using SBT defined artefacts when an external ivysettings is used? If I remove my custom ivy stuff (the two lines below), compilation goes smooth.

This is added to build.sbt:

```
externalIvySettingsURL(url("file:///blabla/ivysettings.xml"))

externalIvyFile(baseDirectory(_ / "dev/build/ivy.xml"))
```

SBT version: 0.13.0

Comment: Which version of SBT are you using?