# How to show download progress while SBT is downloading jars?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, ivy

When I'm using SBT to package my app, it may take a long time to get jars from central maven repository or Typesafe repo. And it would be painful for me to identify if it's stuck while downloading. For example,

```
$ sbt package
[info] Loading project definition from /home/au9ustine/projects/gloin/project
[info] Set current project to gloin (in build file:/home/au9ustine/projects/gloin/)
...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.3/scala-compiler-2.10.3.jar
```

frееzes for a long time occasionally.

I searched a lot and found that it gets stuck on connection issue. However currently I have no idea how to identify when an issue occurs because sometimes connection works well. So, I need to check the progress of downloading files. Something like `wget` provides:

```
$ wget -c http://www.sonatype.org/downloads/nexus-latest-bundle.zip
--2014-12-27 20:00:28--  http://www.sonatype.org/downloads/nexus-latest-bundle.zip
Resolving www.sonatype.org (www.sonatype.org)... 54.85.199.48, 54.165.51.98
Connecting to www.sonatype.org (www.sonatype.org)|54.85.199.48|:80... connected.
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 80393206 (77M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘nexus-latest-bundle.zip’

nexus-latest-bundle 100%[=====================>]  76.67M  67.6KB/s   in 17m 6s

2014-12-27 20:17:41 (76.5 KB/s) - ‘nexus-latest-bundle.zip’ saved [80393206/80393206]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Ivy is responsible for that, it's possible to manage it with Ivy, using `showprogress` attribute of `resolver` ant-task:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/use/resolve.html

But sbt uses Ivy API directly and `showprogress` seems to be hardcoded to false. But, there is a tricky way to achieve what you want: you may implement your own [MessageLogger](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/ivy/util/MessageLogger.java.html), instead of [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/9c442d3aed53bdc89db1ada9d5b204bf02adb339/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/IvyLogger.scala) (see `isShowProgress`). To "register" it, redefine [`withIvy`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/sxr/sbt/Ivy.scala.html#sbt;IvySbt.withIvy(61041e0039)) from `IvySbt` and [`CachedResolutionResolveEngine`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/fda9252250b9ab7265b36cc55a5432489cfa0500/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/ivyint/CachedResolutionResolveEngine.scala) classes:

```
def withIvy[T](log: Logger)(f: Ivy => T): T =
       withIvy(new YourLoggerInterface(log))(f)
```

`IvySbt` class is final, `CachedResolutionResolveEngine` is private, so you should hook `withIvy` call using [dynamic proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13712213/1809978) (it's pretty much simple). At least similar solution worked for me when i was playing with dependency resolving. But it's not much safe of course.

There is also may be a way to define such property in `ivy.xml`, `ivysettings.xml` ([How to use SBT with external ivy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384642/how-to-use-sbt-with-external-ivy-configuration))

Comment: Thanks dk14, though have not tested yet but appreciated your idea :)